# How to return data that user inputs?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I recently learned Angular2. Currently, I have got a material modal after some searching. However,I can't find how I return the data that the user can input.

In the modal I currently have, there is one input field and one checkbox. When close the console logs "de dialog closed" and "true".

This is my modal HTML:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add Group</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Groupname">

    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-checkbox >Private group?</mat-checkbox>

    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">img</button>

    </mat-form-field>

  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>cancel</button>
  <!-- The mat-dialog-close directive optionally accepts a value as a result for the dialog. -->
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" >save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { GroupsService} from '../../../services/Groups.service';
import { Groups } from '../../../models/groupModel'
import {  MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-groups',
  templateUrl: './groups.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./groups.component.scss'],
})
export class GroupsComponent implements OnInit {

  animal: string;
  name: string;
  groups: Groups[];

  constructor(
    private groupsService: GroupsService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.groupsService.getMyGroups()
      .then(group =>{
        this.groups = group;
        console.log(this.groups)
      }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      height: '300px',
      width: '300px',
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      console.log(result);
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

  testgroup(id){
  console.log(id)
  }
  acceptGroup(){
    console.log('accept')
  }
  declineGroup(){
    console.log('decline');
  }
  createGroup(){
    console.log("sample");
  }

}
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './model.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code inside HTML template is currently responsible for what you're passing back from the model: `[mat-dialog-close]="true"`. As you see you're just passing `true` and nothing else. Simplest way to achieve what you want is to create form inside the dialog and pass its value.

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add Group</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form #modalForm="ngForm">
    <div>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput name="groupName" placeholder="Groupname" ngModel>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox name="privateGroup" ngModel>Private group?</mat-checkbox>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">img</button>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="modalForm.value">save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

You can also pass form value on submit (using `(ngSubmit)="mySubmitFunction(modalForm.value)"` on form tag ) to the `mySubmitFunction` defined in `DialogOverviewExampleDialog`. And then, after some kind of validation for example, pass data by using: `this.dialogRef.close(someVariableContainingValues)`.

Comment: do you also know how i read the checkbox and how i set the img button to accept a file? if i put the checkbox in a mat-form field i get the folowing: " mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl."

Comment: checkbox worked, i put it together with the inputbox in the matform, just need the button

Comment: Great idea! this was the best solution for my case

Answer (score 0):

use this code i think it will be work:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      console.log(result);
      //this.animal = result;
    }).()=>{
      this.animal = result;
};
```